# Nextjs Hydration Failed Mismatched Time between Client and Server

Tags: reactjs, next.js, hydration

So I'm creating a timeline component in a Next app and while rendering the UI this error is getting thrown in the console

> Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "May 2022 - Present" Client: "Apr 2022 - Invalid Date

> Error: Text content does not match
> server-rendered HTML.

> Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

> Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.

Here's the code snippet

```
const Timeline = ({experiences}) => {
      experiences.forEach((experience) => {
      experience.startDate =  new Date(experience.startDate).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { year: 'numeric', month: 'short' });
      experience.endDate = experience.endDate ? new Date(experience.endDate).toLocaleDateString('en-US', {year: 'numeric', month: 'short'}): 'Present';
      });

    return (
       <div>
         {experiences.map((experience,idx) => (
           <div key={`timeline-item-${idx}`}>
            {`${experience.startDate} - ${experience.endDate}`}
           </div>))}
       </div>
```

Comment: There's a mismatch between the dates generated on the server when the page gets pre-render, and the dates generated on the client during hydration. You can move the logic that sets the `startDate` and `endDate` inside a `useEffect` to force the dates to only be generated on the client and prevent the mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

That's because your server and client have different locales. You could force client side rendering by using useEffect and useState hooks. Here is sample of useClientSideDate hook. (I am using luxon to handle dates).

```
export const useClientSideDate = (isoDate: string | null): string | null => {
  const [localDate, setLocalDate] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isoDate) {
      const dateTime = DateTime.fromISO(isoDate);
      setLocalDate(dateTime.isValid ? dateTime.toLocaleString() : null);
    } else {
      setLocalDate(null);
    }
  }, [isoDate]);

  return localDate;
};
```